# Cannot boot into Windows after using Partition Magic

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, partition-magic

By mistake I ran Partition Magic for XP and updated a partition. When I restarted the computer, it froze with a stop 0x0000007B (0x80D86B58, 0xC0000034, 0x00000000) error. I was unable to run chkdsk. I tried `bootrec /fixmbr` and `fixboot`, now when the computer restarts I get a message saying "Bootmgr is missing". I ran diskpart and this is what I get:

```
list disk

Disk ###      Status   Size     Free
Free disk 0   Online   596 GB   1024 KB

select disk 0

list partition

Partition ###   Type      Size     Offset
Partition 1     Primary    39 MB   31 KB
Partition 2     Primary    13 GB   40 MB
Partition 3     Primary   582 GB   13 GB

select partition 3
```

When I list volumes I can't see my partitions. What am I missing?

I tried booting from a Ubuntu Linux pen drive, and I was able to see my files. What do I need to do to boot correctly into Windows?

When running automatic startup repair I get the following in the log:

> Root cause found: system volume on disk is corrupt

Comment: Hey I forget, but PM messed up my disk too, I used the Easus partiton master program to "fix" it.  PM is no longer useful for win7 for some reason.  Attempting to fix and checkdisk it could make it worse.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend running chkdsk in read-only mode to evaluate how bad off the partition damage is.  If page after page after page of errors scroll by it maybe hopeless.  If you only have a few errors then chkdsk /f c: might be safe.